# continuously subscribe to the portfolio data with IBroker package?

Tags: portfolio, ibrokers

I tried to use reqUpdateAccounts, but it is just a snapshot. I would like to monitor the portfolio on a continuous basis. I understand .reqUpdateAccounts could subscribe to the portfolio data, but don't know how to present and handle the data properly? I know this is probably very basic, but I am not familiar with R and haven't found a good example. Can someone give a good way to monitor the portfolio data continuously with IBrokers? Thanks.